# Отследить нажатие Shift/Ctrl в комбинации с Enter

Tags: c#, wpf, button

`<Button Content="Кнопка" Click="Button_Click" IsDefault="True"/>`

Есть такая кнопка. Хочется, чтобы её поведение отличалось в случаях:

1. Нажат Enter.
2. Нажата комбинация Shift+Enter.
3. Нажата комбинация Ctrl+Enter.

Как реализовать метод `Button_Click` в таком случае?

Comment: Вроде бы надо проверять, нажата ли комбинация при клике на кнопку.

Comment: Как реализовать эту проверку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void button1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) 
{
   if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) == Keys.Shift) 
   {
     MessageBox.Show("Pressed " + Keys.Shift);
   }
}
```

[Determining Which Modifier Key Was Pressed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984219.aspx)

Comment: Спасибо, сработало!

Comment: @ResPasha, пометьте ответ как верный.